# ss is replacing netstat, how can I get it to list ports similarly to what I am used to?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, socket, netstat

I've been trying to modernise my way with Linux by, for one thing, ditching netstat for ss. I looked up my favourite command line flag for netstat in the ss man pages, and was very glad to find that `netstat -lnp` is more or less the same command as `ss -lnp`. Or so I thought...

```
# ss -lnp | grep 1812
```

Turns up nothing, but

```
# netstat -lnp | grep 1812
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1812            0.0.0.0:*                           11103/radiusd
```

does. A fact that made that particular troubleshooting unnecessarily harder.

Now I'm trying to understand how I should have used ss to verify that the daemon was listening.

Can someone please explain?

EDIT:

```
# ss --version
ss utility, iproute2-ss090324
# ss -aunp | grep radi
UNCONN     0      0                         *:50482                    *:*      users:(("radiusd",11103,11))
UNCONN     0      0                 127.0.0.1:18120                    *:*      users:(("radiusd",11103,9))
UNCONN     0      0                         *:1812                     *:*      users:(("radiusd",11103,6))
UNCONN     0      0                         *:1813                     *:*      users:(("radiusd",11103,7))
UNCONN     0      0                         *:1814                     *:*      users:(("radiusd",11103,10))
# ss -lnp | grep radi
#
```

Comment: Does `radiusd` show at all in `ss`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A recent version of `ss` should also display UDP listeners in that way. You can limit to UDP with `ss -unlp`.

I have tried a recent Debian version where `ss --version` reports `ss utility, iproute2-ss140804` and that does work.

On A Red Hat 5 system with `ss utility, iproute2-ss061002` it doesn't. You do get more info there using `ss -aunp` although that also shows connected ports.

You can also try:

```
ss -apu state unconnected 'sport = :1812'
```

Comment: Odd, none of these commands work on a Raspberry Pi with ss version `ss140804`. However, they work perfectly on Fedora with ss version `ss170501`. I guess that's what happens when I use three year old software :(

Comment: That's why I wrote "A recent version ..." :-)